# Why I can't get values of my JSON file?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, kotlin

Hello I am trying to extract the datas of my JSON file with Kotlin in Android studio :

Here is my JSON file :

```
val future = RequestFuture.newFuture < JSONObject > ()
val request = JsonObjectRequest("localhost", JSONObject(), future, future)
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
requestQueue.add(request)

try {

  val array = JSONObject().getJSONArray("server_response")
  for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
    val objectYear = array.getJSONObject(i)
    val year = objectYear.getString("birthday")


    val response = future.get() // this will block
    textView2.setText(year.toString) // It does not work
  }
} catch (e: JSONException) {
  e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I would like to display the value year in my textView2,thank you for your help !!!

Comment: can you change `year.toString` to `year.toString()` and try again?

Comment: I try but it does not work :/ I get TextView instead of 1968 I think the problem comes from `val array = JSONObject().getJSONArray("server_response")` because if I put for instance `textView2.setText("fdsf")` above it works whereas if it below it does not work.

Comment: where is your json data variable? JSONObject() is Class. its not your json data variable.

Comment: I guess here : `objectYear.getString("birthday")`

Comment: no. Kotlin 'JSONObject()' mean Java 'new JSONObject()'

Comment: 'JSONObject().getJSONArray("server_response")' is always size 0

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var jsonData = JSONObject()
val future = RequestFuture.newFuture < JSONObject > ()
var listener = Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {
            try {

                val array = response.getJSONArray("server_response")
                for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                    val objectYear = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    val year = objectYear.getString("birthday")
                    val response = future.get() // this will block
                    textView2.setText(year.toString) // It does not work
                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
val request = JsonObjectRequest("localhost",jsonData , listener , future)
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
requestQueue.add(request)
requestQueue.start()
```

Comment: Thank you but I have the same problem I feel this line is wrong : `  val array = jsonData.getJSONArray("server_response")`

Comment: Sorry but I got TextView and not 1968 ;(